# Php вернуть ошибку приложению

Tags: php, java, android

Здравствуйте.
Приложение подключается к БД на сервере, где, например, пытается добавить в столбец username "Вася". Все значения столбца username уникальны. На php кое-как я сделал так, чтобы вписывалось только уникальное значение в этот столбец, но как, в том случае, если, например, "Вася" уже есть вернуть и обработать приложению (android) сообщение об этом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Заставьте PHP-скрипт выводить, через `echo` например, результат его работы. Что-нибудь типа строки/числа. Например `success/error` или `0/1` для успешной вставки/ошибки.
2. При обращении к этому PHP-скрипту вы в виде ответа сервера получите эти значения и уже в этот момент можете их обработать как угодно на стороне android-приложения.

Comment: Точно, спасибо!

Comment: @Schepalin, пожалуйста)